# Facebook Android API asks for additional permission

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using v2.3 api here I can login with Facebook login button. Now how can I call additional permission on click? I have looked through answers for this question, but all of them look to be back-dated.

Can someone show me the right way of asking for addition permission and perform further action(s) based on that?

I am able to get the user's basic info and I now need need post permission to post something in user's wall

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) this.findViewById(R.id.login_button);


loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
   AccessToken act = loginResult.getAccessToken();

}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the loginManager to add more permission. you can add it on click button or on create view or fragment

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
    fragmentOrActivity,
    Arrays.asList("user_friends"));
```

You can also get AccessToken via following if needed after getting new permission

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it after `findViewById` method of `LoginButton`

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) this.findViewById(R.id.login_button);

loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends","email");  //Add permissions here

loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
       AccessToken act = loginResult.getAccessToken();

    }
});
```

Comment: How is the code different from my question. and i need to add permission after login not at the time of login

Answer (score 0):

In facebook v4 you can define permissions like

loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList
              ("publish_actions","user_friends", "email" , "user_photos" ));
so on...

Comment: I said after not all together at the same time

Comment: You can first ask for all permissions and then set permission on session object.  Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        // Check for publish permissions
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                    this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;  } }

Comment: 2.3 does not have Session object. publish_action cant be in read permission